# How to use second inlinekeyboard in Telegram bot?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I can perfectly use every button from the first inlinekeyboard(self._morebuttons1) and I can open the second inlinekeyboard(self._morebuttons2) from the first one, but no one button work on second inlinekeyboard, probably because of callback_data. I tried to return to the beginning of the function, but always get the error `NameError: name '_morebuttons1' is not defined`.

How is it possible to use two or more inlinekeyboards?

Example of my code:

```
        handles = [
            CommandHandler('One', self._one),
            CommandHandler('morebuttons2', self._morebuttons2),
            CommandHandler('Three', self._three),
            CommandHandler('morebuttons1', self._morebuttons1),
        ]
        callbacks = [
            CallbackQueryHandler(self._morebuttons1_inline),
            CallbackQueryHandler(self._morebuttons2_inline),

    def _morebuttons1(self, update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:

        keyb = [[InlineKeyboardButton('One', callback_data='1')],
        [InlineKeyboardButton('To the second inlinekeyboard', callback_data='2')]]
        menu_choices = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyb)
        update.message.reply_text("start with commands 1", reply_markup=menu_choices)
        
        for handle in handles:
            self._updater.dispatcher.add_handler(handle)

        for callback in callbacks:
            self._updater.dispatcher.add_handler(callback)


    def _morebuttons_inline(self, update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:   
        
        if update.callback_query:
           
           msg = update.callback_query

           
           if msg.data == '1':
            self._one(update, context),
            
           if msg.data == '2':
            self._morebuttons2(update, context)
            
            
            
        return _morebuttons1
           
            
    def _morebuttons2(self, update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:

        keyb = [[InlineKeyboardButton('Three', callback_data='3')],
        [InlineKeyboardButton('Back to the first inlinekeyboard', callback_data='4')]]
        menu_choices = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyb)
        update.callback_query.message.edit_text("start with commands 2", reply_markup=menu_choices)             
            
            
    def _morebuttons2_inline(self, update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:   
        if update.callback_query:
           msg = update.callback_query
           
           
           if msg.data == '3':
            self._three(update, context),
            
           if msg.data == '4':
            self._morebuttons1(update, context) 
           
        return _morebuttons2
```

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jamreg/TelegramBotTest/glc/tg1.py", line 69, in wrapper
    return command_handler(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jamreg/TelegramBotTest/glc/tg1.py", line 1058, in _morebuttons1_inline
    return _morebuttons1
NameError: name '_morebuttons1' is not defined
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: Can you show the full traceback? Also it would be helpful to see a runnable examples instead of only the callbacks …

Comment: I added full traceback to the code from CommandHadlers till Inlinekeyboards. :) @CallMeStag

Comment: I don't see a traceback. A traceback is the big blog of text that's printed when the exception happens. It tells you where it happend. For the code: Please read https://telegra.ph/Minimal-Working-Example-for-PTB-07-18

Comment: i added traceback

Comment: Ah. I should probably be `return self._morebuttons1` instead of `return _morebuttons1`. But I can't tell for sure without an MWE.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Just merge all data from  `self._morebuttons_inline`
and `self._morebuttons2_inline` together. Thanks @CallMeStag for help :)